# Error in my ruby code

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I can't get this code to work. Can anyone help me by pointing out the error in this code so that I can understand where I made mistakes?

```
    STDOUT.print 'Do you wish to input another length in meters? '
more = STDIN.getString        
more = STDIN.getint( );
more = more.toUpper( )
while(more[1] = 'Y')
  STDOUT.puts 'Enter length in meters: '
  gets(meter)
  f = meter * 3.28084
  feet = f.toInt
  inches = (12.0 * (feet - f)).to_i

  print 'The length is '

  if feet = 1
    STDIN.print feet + 'foot ';
  else
    STDOUT.print feet + 'feet '
  if inches = 1
    STDOUT.print inches + ' inch.\n'
  else if (inches < 1)
    STDOUT inches + ' inches.\n'
  else
    STDOUT.print '.\n'

  STDOUT.print 'Do you wish to input another length in meters: '
  more = STDIN.getint
end
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting? There seems to be several syntax errors in this piece of code.

Comment: meter-to-ft-in.rb:31 syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyward_end

Comment: You need an `end` for your `if` block (probably several, actually). Among other problems.

Comment: i'm still getting error in line 36 which is STDOUT inches + inches ".\n"

Comment: I think it's upset b/c the last else is not expected, there are no open ifs to have an else.

Answer (score 4):

Where do I start?

- In Ruby, you need to terminate your blocks with `end`. You did it for `while`, but not for `if`.
- Ruby uses `elsif`; you can't write `else if`.
- Ruby does not have `toInt`; it's called `to_i`, as you use in the very next line
- `gets(meter)` is an error; you need to say `meter = gets`
- `STDIN` does not have `getString`, it has `gets`. It also doesn't have `getint`, you need to write `gets.to_i`.
- `toUpper` does not exist, use `upcase`, as in `more = more.upcase`. You can also use the more readable and more efficient `more.upcase!`.
- In `if` and `while`, you have assignment `=`, where you presumably want to have comparison `==`.
- `more[1]` is the *second* character of `more`; the first being `more[0]`.
- `more = ...` is being called twice in a row. That means the first value you input will be discarded without effect.
- `STDIN.print` is an obvious mistake for `STDOUT.print`.
- You can use `puts "..."` instead of `print "...\n"`.
- `STDIN` and `STDOUT` are redundant when you are using `gets`, `print` and others; `STDIN.gets` is identical to `gets`, `STDOUT.print` is identical to `print`.
- `STDOUT inches + ' inches.\n'` is an obvious mistake, since `STDOUT` is not a function.
- `'.\n'` contains three characters: a period, a backslash and a letter. The double-quoted `".\n"` contains two: a period and a newline.
- Ruby does not typically use `;`, and it does not usually use empty parentheses for calling 0-parameter functions. These are just stylistic errors, and won't impact runtime.

There may or may not be more.

Comment: Ok I point our error in comment but i'm still getting error in line 36

which is

    STDOUT inches + inches ".\n"

Comment: You don't have an error. You have a *list of errors longer than your code*. Fix all of them first, then post what you have then if you still have errors. I addressed that error in my 13th bullet: `STDOUT` is not a function, you wanted to write `STDOUT.print` like in other similar lines.